# CSS menu items full width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the menu links (under Menu) on the following website fill the full width of the bar.  So when you have "Soup & Salad" as active, it extends all the way to the left of the blue bar.  There should also be no space between blocks when you hover over the link next to the active state.

http://www.woodonwellington.com/

```
ul#menuNav
{
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
background-color: #0c0648;
padding-top: 13px;
padding-bottom: 12px;

}

#menuNav li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;

}

#menuNav a { 
padding-top: 13px; 
padding-bottom: 13px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because your li is set to `display:inline;` In your code you have an enter and a couple of spaces/tabs between the `<li></li>` blocks. To fix this you have to write the tags right after eachother. You want to limit the space between those `<li>` tags.

In stead of this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
</ul>
```

Do this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Content
    </li><li>
        Content
    </li><li>
        Content
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Answer on comment:**

The same problem appeared on the link itself. As you can see on the image below you made the li elements touch eachother.

[image]

Now to make the links touch eachother you have to do the same.

Instead of:

```
<li>
    <a>Link</a>
<li>
```

Do this:

```
<li><a>
    Link
</a><li>
```

It is not a nice solution but it will fix your spacing between the links.

Comment: That's right. Another solution would be to make the list items `display: block;` and have them `float: left;`, but that would require further changes both in the css and in the markup.

Comment: I've made this change to the <li> elements, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Changing to display: block seems to have worked better.  Still tweaking to try and get the menu to render fully across the blue bar.

Comment: @user1110562 I'm glad you found a way to fix it. I made an edit with another possible solution.

Comment: I have it setup so the menu <li>'s span across the width of the menu bar, but still can't get the active / hover states to take up the entire width of the <li>'s that they are in.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the display: inline; in your .css and add float:left;

```
#menuNav li
{    
list-style-type: none;
background-color:red;
float:left;
}
```

This will remove all the spaces.

Check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/BishanMeddegoda/30w56oft/

Answer (score 0):

you could use display:table/table-cell to acomplish this:

basic CSS to apply:

```
#menuNav {
display:table;
width:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
#menuNav li{
display:table-cell;
}
#menuNav li a {
display:block;
text-align:center;
}
```

*remove any floats from CSS to test this. float kills display (unlesss set to `flex`, but this is another option)*